# How does a software like Cheat Engine work?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

[Cheat Engine](https://www.cheatengine.org/) is a tool for searching and modifying the memory of other running processes. I used to think this was pretty much trivial: going to an address and simply modifying it. But I realize now that things are not that simple. Each process has its own virtual memory and two processes can't play with each other's memory. So how exactly is Cheat Engine able to violate [process isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation) and modify other processes' memory?

Answer (score 4):

A process can be attached to another process such that it has access to that process's memory. This is designed for debugging programs - a debugger needs to be attached to the process being debugged, and needs to be able to read any memory data, break execution, edit memory data, inject code, etc. Cheat Engine just re-purposes these debugger functions in order to cheat in games.

Comment: So, how is memory protection useful if a process has these kind of means for interprocess memory access?

Comment: @Gonzalo on Linux there are the user permissions, a normal user can't attach a process as a debugger to one which belongs to root, you can make this attach only if you have the right permissions what make the protection still useful

Comment: Attaching to a process as debugger sends `sigstop`s, doesn't it? Not sure about Windows, but at least that's the way Linux works, this makes every read and write to the process memory safe (no race conditions) but makes the process paused for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Reading about [GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdb) may shed some light on this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668/reading-other-process-memory-in-os-x-bsd) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473908/can-gdb-change-the-assembly-code-of-a-running-program) discuss similar things.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer